# android popup window to run in background

Tags: android, popupwindow

how do I set android popup window to run in background. I mean, I dont need to make the app open, but it will run in background, and when call, popup will appeared on android main menu. I got the `handler` script, I just only want to know how do i set this popup to show on any screen, just like `toast message` will do.

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater  =         (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
            final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  

            final PopupWindow popupWindowDi = new PopupWindow(popupView,      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

            Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);                          
            btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindowDi.dismiss();
            }});
            popupWindowDi.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need a system dialog which is shown over all activities-the facebook implements chat heads.Use this in your code:

```
popup.getWindow().setType(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG);
popup.show();
```

Make sure you add SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission in your manifest.refer
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW